# Callback from framework for out of memory in Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory

In android,is there any callback that is called when system runs low on memory or out of memory occurs.

For eg: there are three applications A,B,C running.In C out of memory is thrown.How can the application A come to know that so that it can clear its resources ,so that the android system wont kill the application A.

Answer (score 2):

You must extend the Application class, and override onLowMemory() method.

```
public class App extends Application {


    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

        super.onLowMemory();
        // handle lowmemory stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This works sometimes, but I've found it flaky, especially if you have JNI components.  It seems like it isn't always called.  Worth trying, but don't put a lot of faith in it.

Comment: hi..just for testing purpose..how can i force the system to call onLowMemory().I tried creating an integer array of size 10000 and put it inside a for loop which executed for 10000 times.As a result i got out of memory exception.But in my other application where i implemented the onLowMemory ,the function did not get called.So can u please tell me how to test it?

Answer (score 0):

Besides onLowMemory() there are other methods.

Use [WeakReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to keep your cache and Android will handle OOM gracefully. Also, you can use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), which has higher priority than activities and will be destroyed after them.

Comment: WeakReference does not work on Android 2.3 and up.  They changed it so that weak references are NEVER kept unless a strong reference also exists.  Instead, if you want to cache data use an LRUCache, which is backported to 2.3 via the support library.

Comment: What about SoftReference ?

Comment: Already found an answer. SoftReference fits better for this case, but Android SDK still recommends to use android.util.LruCache instead.

Comment: The docs say that because thats what the official Java docs say.  SoftReferences are treated the same way in Android-  they both are freed as soon as no strong references exist.

Answer (score 0):

> override onLow memory method and do the stuff that you needed.

```
    @Override
public void onLowMemory() {

// clear the unwanted resources from memory

    super.onLowMemory();
}
```

> NOTE: There is no guarantee that this method will be invoked correctly.
>
> This is called when the overall system is running low on memory, and would like actively running process to try to tighten their belt. While the exact point at which this will be called is not defined, generally it will happen around the time all background process have been killed, that is before reaching the point of killing processes hosting service and foreground UI that we would like to avoid killing.

From developer Docs  [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory%28%29)